# Proving that an isomorphism from a vector space $X$ to $X'$ using symmetric bilinear forms is onto

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form, vector-space-isomorphism

Here's the problem:

Let $f$ be a symmetric bilinear form over an n-dimensional vector space $X$, and $f$ is non-degenerate (for all nonzero $x \in X$, there exists $y \in X$ so $f(x,y) \neq 0$). Prove that $L_f: X \to X'$ defined as $x \mapsto f(x, -)$ is an isomorphism.

I can easily prove $L_f$ is one-to-one, and argue that it's an isomorphism since we are dealing with finite-dimensional spaces. (If $L_f(x) = L_f(y)$ then $f(x-y, z) = 0$ for all $z$. However, since $f$ is non-degenerate, if $x-y \neq 0$ then there would exist a $z$ that would make $f$ nonzero. Therefore, $x=y$)

However, I am stuck trying to prove that it is onto, to maybe extend this result to infinite dimensional spaces. Is it even possible?

Comment: the result does not hold for infinite-dimensional vector spaces. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-i